# Undetected-Chromedriver Version Mismatch with Chrome Auto-Updates

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have been using the `undetected-chromedriver` library. While it works well initially, I frequently encounter a version mismatch error after Chrome auto-updates.

Here's the error I encounter:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:55731
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version XXX
Current browser version is XXX.X.XXXX.XX
```

Things I've tried:

1. Reinstalling `undetected-chromedriver`.
2. Specifying the Chrome version while instantiating the driver.
3. Checked GitHub repository issues and discussions for `undetected-chromedriver` for any ongoing compatibility discussions.

I understand that `undetected-chromedriver` uses a patched version of `chromedriver`, which makes it tricky to simply replace it with the latest standard `chromedriver`.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? How do you handle the version mismatch due to Chrome's automatic updates? Are there any long-term solutions or best practices to manage this?

Thanks in advance for any insights or solutions!

Answer (score 1):

There is an open defect for this issue:

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1477

Until it is fixed, you can do the following:

1. Upgrade `undetected-chromedriver` to latest version
2. Set the path of `116` chrome manually, see code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path="C:/full path here/chromedriver.exe") # 116 chromedriver.exe
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.close()
```

Download `chromedriver.exe` for `116` from here:

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Answer (score 0):

Until the fix for https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1477 is available, you can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode as an alternative, which has a modified version of `undetected-chromedriver` with multiple fixes included.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

(An example of bypassing cloudflare detection)

---

SeleniumBase also has other formats with its own API:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.sleep(3)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1"):
        sb.get_new_driver(undetectable=True)
        sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
        sb.sleep(3)
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because your install version of undetected-chromedriver doesn't support
latest version of Chrome browser.

just Update the `undetected-chromedriver` using:

```
pip install --upgrade undetected-chromedriver
```