# undetected-chromedriver isn't being able to use the correct version of chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to use undetected-chromedriver to login to a google account from a Mac. However, when I run the code below I get this error message: "Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:49806
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96"

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless') 

with Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

I already downloaded the latest version of chromedriver from this website[text](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) and I have placed the chromedriver in the same folder as my script, but it still says that my chromedriver is outdated. I don't know what to do, I'm thinking maybe it's because the latest version of undetected-chromedriver doesn't support chrome 116.0.5845.96 yet...?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76928119/7598774

Comment: @Shawn thank you very much! The second solution of the link you suggested worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing chromedriver as a service object

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromedriver_path=Service("ENTER LATEST CHROMEDRIVER PATH HERE")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromedriver_path, options=chromeOptions)  
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

Also, please do ensure your Chrome version and Chromedriver version are the same by checking your chrome settings and also you have downloaded the correct chromedriver for your system.

Comment: hey Marvin, thanks for the help! But I was wondering, does this work for undetected-chromedriver as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. If nothing is working for you, then delete currently present chrome driver binary inside /usr/bin/.
2. After that the location where chrome driver is present should be empty. Remove any other binary for chrome driver if present.
3. Now simply try running any simple selenium test and the latest chrome driver will be downloaded automatically.

Comment: Hey Mukund, I tried your suggestion but still got the same error. I'm starting to believe that the reason may be that undetected-chromedriver is not compatible with my version of  Chrome, which is  116.0.5845.96, given that when I use "driver = webdriver.Chrome()" instead of "driver = uc.Chrome()" my code works. However it doesn't pass anti-bot tests.